# Releasing a Team name

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

I started creating a team. I used my company name. When I arrived to the second step I noticed I was logged in as my personal user instead of my work one. I did not finish the team creation.

I logged out and logged back in with my work user, tried to create the team using the same name but now it tells me the name is not available. It seems to be reserved for my other user, even if I did not finish the process.

Is there a way to release the team name from my personal user so my work user can create the team?

---

Update:

- I noticed that after a few hours (12 more or less) the name was released. I am not sure if it was automatically (due to the team not being finished) or if it was due to an action taken by the Stack Exchange team. See next point.
- I contacted the Stack Exchange customer service team about this problem. They confirmed that there is no way of doing so from the user perspective. They mentioned they were going to ask their development team to work on this. After a few hours, they sent an update indicating the team name was release and I could try creating it from my work user. I am very pleased with the customer service response, but since this is not really a solution, I will leave the question open.

Comment: The team name was released automatically but not by the SE staff.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to release your team name for creating the team on another account.
Complete the following steps to create your team without releasing your team name.

1. Create your team on your personal account.
2. Now go to your team page.
3. Click <kbd>Settings</kbd> from the sidebar.
4. Go to the <kbd>Invite</kbd> tab.
5. Click <kbd>Invite members</kbd>.
6. Enter the email that you used sign up with the work account.
7. Click <kbd>Send invites</kbd>.
8. Check the mail that you used in step 6. for new messages.
9. Open the new email from `Stack Overflow For Teams` and click the link to join the team.
10. Log in if needed.
11. Go to your personal account.
12. Go to your team page.
13. Click <kbd>Settings</kbd> from the sidebar.
14. Go to the <kbd>Manage</kbd> tab.
15. Find your work account from the list.
16. Click the <kbd>Member</kbd> link/button near your account's name.
17. Click <kbd>Make Team Admin</kbd>
18. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> on the dialog box.
19. Now switch to your work account.
20. Click <kbd>Settings</kbd> from the sidebar.
21. Go to the <kbd>Manage</kbd> tab.
22. Find your personal account from the list.
23. Click the <kbd>Admin</kbd> link/button near your account's name.
24. Click <kbd>Revoke Admin status</kbd>
25. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> on the dialog box.
26. Click the <kbd>Member</kbd> link/button near your account's name.
27. Click <kbd>Deactivate user</kbd>
28. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> on the dialog box.

Now you can use the team like if it was created on the work account.

Note: The payment information and other contact information that you entered while creating the team will be associated with the team, not the account.
But still it will be possible to see your personal account in the `Deactivated` tab.

Comment: Thanks! But if I do it this way, I would have to enter the payment information under my personal account. I am not sure my company would be happy with that.

Comment: @cockypup The payment information won't be associated with your account. It will be associated with the team and all details that you enter like contact information will be associated with the team.

Comment: While this might function, it's often desirable to keep business and personal *completely* separate. Under some conditions, not doing so may have significant legal consequences, or just be something that the user wants to do from a privacy point of view. So, a preferred solution would be for the user to be able to completely abandon/delete the record of a partially created Team. There may be no solution for this, other than contacting SE through "contact us".

Comment: @Makyen: I agree. I did not feel comfortable asking the card holder from my company to let me associate the payment info with my personal account, even if it was temporary.  contacted SE  and they confirmed there is no self-serve solution yet. They did release the name for me, but since that is not really a solution, I will leave the question open. I will add notes about that.

Comment: @cockypup Having to contact SE through "contact us" is a solution and should be in an Answer. Sure, it'd be nice if there was a self-serve method of doing this, but given that's not currently the case, then "contact us" is *the* current clean way to do it. This Answer is helpful, and is likely to be beneficial to people, but it's not a clean solution for all people in this situation. Having another Answer posted gives people the information that there's no current way to do it cleanly by yourself would be good. I'd suggest you self-answer.